# Ace editor - unbind change event

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Why do these methods to unbind the 'change' event in ace not work?

How can I resolve this problem?

```
editor.getSession().removeEventListener('change',callback);
```

and

```
editor.getSession().off('change',callback);
```

Comment: How are you attaching the event handler?

Comment: @Amy I use this : `editor.on('change', callback);`

Comment: then use `editor.off('change', callback);`. You can't remove callback from session, if it was added to the editor in the first place!

Comment: So there is no way to unbind this? Thanks a lot!